# MongoDB or mongoclient not closing connections

Tags: php-fpm, mongodb

I'm having an issue with our mongodb server having too many connections open. We have tracked down the problem to be related to the incoming connections from the vhost with the php server.

```
sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP | grep ESTABLISHED | grep -c '10.0.0.40'
```

Get's about **8000** open connections.

On the php vhost, there are only **40** connections open to the database vhost

```
sudo lsof | grep -c '10.0.0.60'
```

We tried to force close the connections with tcp kill, but they keep coming back.

Why is the mongo vhost having so many open connections when in reality there should be only 40 ?

How do i make mongodb close existing connections that are hanged ?

How to find the culprit on the php server side ?  Does php5-fpm support connection poooling ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is using connection pool, also application can decide how many connection it required, please check your mongodb and application settings to reduce it.